# How and why float main() in C working?

Tags: c

I tried to google it and I found that main() in C has return type 'int' . if it is 'void' it is internally treated as 'int' . 'float' or 'double' is not allowed . But when I am writing this in code blocks :

```
double main()
{
printf("hello");
return 0;
}
```

it is executed successfully .
I want know how this is possible.

Comment: Using return type other than `int` are all undefined behaviors. That's it.

Comment: "it is executed successfully" but did the program _return_ the expected `0.0`?  Simply executing the code does not show that.  You need a way to test the return value of your program to know it `"executed successfully".

Comment: Even if the program compiles, the compiler doesn't emit any warning, and it returns `0.0`, it still doesn't mean it's a valid C program.

Comment: Who cares?   Yet again, 'I did a stupid thing and want the consequences explained'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 'I did a stupid thing and want the consequences explained'

Comment: That is what compiler warnings are for. Unless compiled for _freestanding environment_, gcc, for instance, would warn. So: enable warnings and py heed to them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C Standard n1124 says

**§** 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup

> The function called at program startup is named main. The
>   implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be
>   defined with a return type of int and with no parameters: int
>   `main(void) { /* ... */ }` or with two parameters (referred to here as
>   argc and argv, though any names may be used, as they are local to the
>   function in which they are declared):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ /* ... */ }
```

> or equivalent;9) or in some other implementation-defined
>   manner.

Therefore it is undefined what has happened to your program as you do not obey the rules it should adhered to.